# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' when I try running my API request in python

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import json
import csv



csvFile = open("C:/Users/Macy/Desktop/Scripts/test.csv", 'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow(('City', 'Name', 'Age','Sex','Race'))

STAGGER_TIME = 1 # of seconds
CityList = ('Canton')


for city in CityList:
    response = urlopen("https://thecountedapi.com/api/counted/?state=TX&city="+city).read().decode('utf-8')
    responseJson = json.loads(response)
    print("--------------")
    print("City: " + str(responseJson.get("city")))
    print("Name: " + str(responseJson.get("name")))
    print("Age: " + str(responseJson.get("age")))
    print("Sex: " + str(responseJson.get("sex")))
    print("Race: " + str(responseJson.get("race")))
    writer.writerow((responseJson.get("name"), responseJson.get("age"), responseJson.get("sex"), responseJson.get("race"), responseJson.get("city")))
    time.sleep(STAGGER_TIME)

csvFile.close()
```

This is the code that I'm trying to run in Python. Everytime I try running this code, I get an error stating:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Macy/Desktop/Texas A&M/Junior Year/Fall Semester/ISYS 281/shooting.py", line 20, in <module>
    print("City: " + str(responseJson.get("city")))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Where am I going wrong in this code? I've tried researching the problem but all the sources I find are confusing to me.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import json
import csv



csvFile = open("C:/Users/Macy/Desktop/Scripts/test.csv", 'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow(('City', 'Name', 'Age','Sex','Race'))



CityList = ('Canton')


for city in CityList:
    response = urlopen("https://thecountedapi.com/api/counted/?state=TX&city="+city).read().decode('utf-8')
    responseJson = json.loads(response)[0]
    print("--------------")
    print("City: " + responseJson.get["city"])
    print("Name: " + (responseJson.get["name"])
    print("Age: " + (responseJson.get["age"])
    print("Sex: " + (responseJson.get["sex"])
    print("Race: " + (responseJson.get ["race"])
    writer.writerow((responseJson.get["name"], responseJson.get["age"], responseJson.get["sex"], responseJson.get["race"], responseJson.get["city"]))



csvFile.close()
```

This is some updated code but I'm still getting an invalid syntax error when I run the code.

Comment: `json.loads(response)` is a list.

Comment: `responseJson = json.loads(response)[0]` instead of `responseJson = json.loads(response)`.

Comment: Well, does that run? If not, it isn't an actual answer. You can [edit] this post

Comment: No it doesnt run. Im trying to post it to get help on how to make it run

Comment: I don't have `get["city"]`, just `responseJsonData["city"]`. Check again

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this isn't what you want.

```
CityList = ('Canton') # This is just a string, not a list/tuple

for city in CityList:
    print(city)
```

Output

```
C
a
n
t
o
n
```

You want `['Canton']`. An actual list.

---

Then, your JSON looks like this

```
[  <---- notice the bracket
  {
    '__v': 0,
    '_id': '583ce122f708a72906428d9b',
    'address': 'Texas Hwy 243 and Texas Hwy 64',
```

This is a list. Your code assumes you have a dictionary.

You need to loop over this to get your dictionaries.

```
cities = ['Canton']  # This is a list
for city in cities:
    response = urlopen("https://thecountedapi.com/api/counted/?state=TX&city="+city).read().decode('utf-8')
    for responseJson in json.loads(response):
        print("--------------")
        print("City: " + responseJson["city"])
```

Or just get the first, and only dictionary item.

```
responseJson = json.loads(response)[0]
print("--------------")
print("City: " + responseJson["city"])
```

Then, your SyntaxError...

Compare

```
print("City: " + responseJson.get["city"]) # yours
print("City: " + responseJson["city"])     # mine
```

Comment: I used your suggestion but now I'm getting an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Which suggestion?

Comment: your first option which says to loop over it

Comment: I don't know what you are showing me, but do not post code in the comments

Comment: I posted an answer using the code after I took your suggestion.

Comment: I've edited my answer and it runs fine for me. If you have a SyntaxError, that's a fault with your implementation

Comment: I'm new to Python and the implementations of things are different than other languages that I've used. Would you mind posting your full code so that I can figure out where I'm going wrong? I tend to learn better when I can see the full problem and answer.

Comment: You can either use `data.get("key")`, or `data["key"]`. Square brackets are the Pythonic way to access a dictionary. I have posted the full, relevant code needed to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for breaking it down to me. I finally realized my mistake and learned something new in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with encoding. The content you have is in unicode format. So I will suggest unicodecsv package instead of csv package.
You can install the unicodecsv package by `pip install unicodecsv`

You can implement it like this:

```
import time
import json
import unicodecsv
import requests

with open("C:/Users/Macy/Desktop/Scripts/test.csv", 'w+') as csvFile:
    writer = unicodecsv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(('City', 'Name', 'Age','Sex','Race'))

    STAGGER_TIME = 1 # of seconds
    CityList = ['Canton', 'Canton']

    for city in CityList:
        res = json.loads(requests.get("https://thecountedapi.com/api/counted/?state=TX&city="+city).content)[0]
        print "--------------"
        city, name, age, sex, race = res['city'], res['name'], res['age'], res['sex'], res['race']
        print city,',',name,',',age,',',sex,',',race
        writer.writerow((city, name, age, sex, race))
        time.sleep(STAGGER_TIME)
```

Output:

```
--------------
Canton , Mary Lená Pettiet , 33 , Female , White
--------------
Canton , Mary Lená Pettiet , 33 , Female , White
```